# How can I use a USB/COM port inside of a VSCode development container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, serial-port

From inside of a development container for VSCode (Debian Linux) I'd like to use a COM port for communication via an USB device connnected to the Windows host machine (via WSL2). How can I make the COM port available insie of the container?

**EDIT:**

For WSL2 there is [no official support yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq#can-i-access-the-gpu-in-wsl-2--are-there-plans-to-increase-hardware-support-).

> As of right now WSL 2 does not include serial support, or USB device support.

A corresponding [feature request is tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4322#issuecomment-879271524).

Comment: Are you using WSL 1 or WSL 2?

Comment: Why not find and incorporate a COM port redirector for the [RFC2217](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2217) protocol in both your Windows Host and Docker Container?

Comment: @Codo I'm using WSL2.

Comment: In WSL1 it was easy. COM3 appeared as /dev/ttyS3. In WSL2, it doesn't exist anymore and there is no date for when it will be added (see https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4322#issuecomment-879271524). The same issue mentions a few workarounds though.

Comment: @Codo Thanks a lot. I hoped that support is already there. WSL1 is no option for me. Seems like I've to wait for the feature to be implemented.

Comment: The mechanism I commented on earlier is in this article, so it may be helpful. [DraTeots/ComPort over Network.md](https://gist.github.com/DraTeots/e0c669608466470baa6c)

Comment: @kunif Thanks for this workaround hint. However I'd prefer to beeing able to use an "official" solution (WSL2 builtin support).

Comment: @kunif As your suggestion seems to be the only option right now I'd accept it as solution.

Comment: I've just introduced an article that already exists, so please self-answer the results of your experiments or considerations.

Answer (score 2):

July 2021: As of right now WSL 2 does not include serial support, or USB device support.

Update November 2021: the same FAQ states:

[Skanda Hazarika](https://muckrack.com/skanda-hazarika) reports:

> ### [You can now connect USB devices in Windows Subsystem for Linux under Windows 11](https://www.xda-developers.com/wsl-connect-usb-devices-windows-11/)

> If you’re an active user of Windows Subsystem for Linux and want to access USB devices right from the Linux instance running under WSL, then you’ll be happy to know that there has been a significant progress in this front.
>
> Thanks to Microsoft’s contributions to the open-source **[dorssel/usbipd-win](https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win)** project, you can now enjoy USB passthrough access in WSL.
> It means end users can perform tasks like flashing Android devices under Windows Subsystem for Linux, which are otherwise not supported by the Linux subsystem.
>
> The usbipd-win project is all about creating a solution for sharing locally connected USB devices to other machines, including Hyper-V guests and WSL2. However, the official WSL2 Linux kernel used to lack support for the **[USB/IP protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/usbip_protocol.html)**, requiring users to build the kernel themselves.
>
> Since WSL kernel version 5.10.60.1, the required parameters are configured out of the box, so no manual recompilation is needed.
> Microsoft has also contributed a command line interface to the project to both enable a USB device for sharing on Windows and seamlessly attach it from within WSL.

So if you have:

- migrated/upgraded to [Windows 11](https://www.xda-developers.com/windows-11/)
- applied all WSL updates (through the [Windows Store](https://www.xda-developers.com/windows-subsystem-linux-microsoft-store-windows-11/))

Then, your VSCode should be able to access mounted USB drives through WSL.

Comment: Great to hear that. I'll install Windows 11 and try it out. As soon as I tested it I'll accept the anser.

Comment: I tried this with Docker Containers and I am unable to access usb devices from within the container. I can see the USB just fine from Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11 WSL using lsusb. Using lsusb on my docker container returns command not found even when running on --privileged.

Comment: @bortronx "command not found": is it just a `${PATH}` issue? Or is `lsusb` nowhere to be found?

Comment: @VonC lsusb is nowhere to be found in the container it seems. I was unable to access usb devices from a container at all. I tried giving privilege's and nothing. I am able to access it from Ubuntu running on wsl. Unfortunately I gave up on using this method because even from Ubuntu camera feed would not show up on the applications I tried when using wsl. See someone with same issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5158#issuecomment-972578886

Answer (score 1):

**April 2023**:

Now it is possible to setup the whole chain of access to USB in Windows 10 with docker assuming Ubuntu on WSL2.

1. Make sure you WSL kernel is at least 5.10.60 (you can check with `wsl --status` in windows cmd line)
2. Run the steps mentioned [on the Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb)
3. After you setup you should see your device with `lsusb` (`apt install usbutils`)

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

4. It is possible, that you still don't see it in `/dev`. In this case you need to create a `99-platformio-udev.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and add the definition of your usb device. See the [github](https://github.com/abbradar/dotfiles/blob/master/99-platformio-udev.rules) page for the list which probably will contain your selected device as well.
5. You may need to reload the udev config after this. Note: I found my device actually under `/dev/bus/usb...` rather then as `/dev/ttyUSB`

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
sudo service udev restart
```

6. Finally add `"--device=/dev/..."` to you `.devcontainer` file runArgs section or to your `docker run ...` command. Make sure, that you have root privileges in the container. (logged in as `root` or use `--privileged`)